# How to use Promises with when second function depending on the previous (parse csv file, import it, divide the import in batches)?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, promise

I'm trying to parse a CSV file and import it to MongoDB with help of Mongoose. As you can see in the console.log the documents do not arrive to the database...

I do not know how to fix this, Please help!

My guess I have some bad logic when chaining these methods, because first the csv parser needs to complete and then the import method should kick in. Also inside the import method I'm to handle the big csv file (this is just a sample file, the real one is about 1 million rows long) and divide it in batches of 1000 rows each.

```
connectToMongo("autoMDM");
parseCSV(filePath, options).then(records => {
  bulkImportToMongo(records, "parts.js");
});

const Promise = require("bluebird");
const csv = require("fast-csv");
const path = require("path");
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require("fs"));
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.Promise = require("bluebird");

const filePath = path.join(__dirname, "../../data/parts.csv");
const options = {
  delimiter: ";",
  noheader: true,
  headers: [
    "facility",
    "item_number",
    "part_name",
    "part_description",
    "net_weight",
    "customs_statistical"
  ]
};

const parseCSV = Promise.method((filePath, options) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var records = [];
    csv
      .fromPath(filePath, options)
      .on("data", record => {
        records.push(record);
      })
      .on("end", () => {
        // console.log(records);
        resolve(records);
      });
  });
});


function connectToMongo(databaseName) {
  mongoose
    .connect(`mongodb://localhost:27017/${databaseName}`, {
      keepAlive: true,
      reconnectTries: Number.MAX_VALUE,
      useMongoClient: true
    })
    .then(() => console.log(`You are connected to ${databaseName}`))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

function bulkImportToMongo(arrayToImport, mongooseModel) {
  const Model = require(`../../../models/${mongooseModel}`);
  let batchCount = Math.ceil(arrayToImport.length / 1000);
  let batches = new Array(batchCount);

  let ops = batches.map((_, index) => {
    let batch = arrayToImport.slice(index, index + 100);
    return Model.insertMany(batch);
  });

  return Promise.all(ops).then(results => {
    console.log("results: ", results);
  });
}


// RUNNING THE FUNCTIONS NOW..

connectToMongo("autoMDM");
parseCSV(filePath, options).then(records => {
  bulkImportToMongo(records, "parts.js");
});
```

console.log

```
arrayToImport: [
  { facility: 'SDC',
    item_number: '5534513900',
    part_name: 'SCREW',
    part_description: 'SCREW',
    net_weight: '0,045',
    customs_statistical: '73181569' },
  { facility: 'D36',
    item_number: '5534514200',
    part_name: 'BUSHING',
    part_description: 'BUSHING',
    net_weight: '0,038',
    customs_statistical: '73269098' },
  ... 9655 more items ]
results:  [ undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined ]
```

Comment: Why do you have `connectToMongo, parseCSV, bulkImportToMongo` in the beginning of your script *and* in the very end of it?

Comment: Did you verify that the script works fine on a very short input file (like 10-50 rows)?

Comment: @IgorSoloydenko I declare first the functions and after I run them (in the end)

Comment: `connectToMongo("autoMDM");` is **invoked** twice. Once on line #1, and another time in the end of the script...

Comment: You have right. Please ignore that part. I believe I copied it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

At the bare minimum there's a bug with `connectToMongo()` and `parseCSV()` relation. If the establishing a connection to the database is slower than parsing a CSV file, the things will not work our nicely.

To fix that, you need to make `connectToMongo` return a Promise. That will make possible a reliable "first connect" *then* "processing CSVs":

```
connectToMongo(...)
  .then(() =>
    parseCSV(filePath, options)
      .then(records => bulkImportToMongo(records, "parts.js"))
  );
```